# Where is the Visual Studio 2008 Installation Log

Tags: visual-studio

I have an installation of Visual Studio 2008 that is failing.  Where is the installation log that is generated and what is it's name?

Comment: Yesterday I was installing VS2008 and it was getting stuck about 25% of the way through.  Couldn't install, couldn't uninstall.  Checked the NT system log, found a whole pile of "error on cdrom".  Ejected DVD.  All good.  Just a thought.

Comment: heh, so was I.  The DVD was completely unrelated.  Just some DVD with an error on the disc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `%temp%` folder.

> Logs produced by the Visual Studio
>   2008 setup wrapper:
>
> %temp%\dd_install*.txt
>
> %temp%\dd_error*.txt
>
> %temp%\dd_depcheck*.txt
>
> VSMsiLog*.txt - located in your %temp%
>   directory during Visual Studio 2008
>   setup; moved to
>   %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\\Logs after a successful installation; left in
>   %temp% after a failed installation and
>   after uninstallation